# Scala: Defining a function to be the correct type

Tags: scala

I've been playing around with Scala code and have come up against a compiler error which I don't understand. The code generates a vector of pairs of Ints and then tries to filter it.

```
val L = for (x <- (1 to 5)) yield (x, x * x) 
val f = (x: Int, y: Int) => x > 3
println(L.filter(f))
```

The compiler complains about trying to use `f` as an argument for the `filter` method with the compiler error message being:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : (Int, Int) => Boolean
required: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean
```

How do I define the function `f` correctly to satisfy the required function type? I tried to add extra parentheses around `(x: Int, y: Int)` but this gave:

```
error: not a legal formal parameter
   val f = ((x: Int, y: Int)) => x > 3
            ^
```

Comment: This issue is an argument for removing the distinction between argument lists and tuples.  That is, right now, the `(x,y)` in `f(x,y)` is a different sort of thing than the bare `(x,y)` itself.  Unfortunately, it's technically nontrivial to remove this distinction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`f` has type `Function2[Int, Int, Boolean]`. `L`'s type is `IndexedSeq[Tuple2[Int, Int]]` and so `filter` expects a function of type `Function1[Tuple2[Int, Int], Boolean]`. Every `FunctionN[A, B, .., R]` trait has a method `tupled`, which returns a function of type `Function1[TupleN[A, B, ..], R]`. You can use it here to transform `f` to the type expected by `L.filter`.

```
println(L.filter(f.tupled))
> Vector((4,16), (5,25))
```

Alternatively you can redefine `f` to be a `Function1[Tuple2[Int, Int], Boolean]` as follows and use it directly.

```
val f = (t: (Int, Int)) => t._1 > 3
println(L.filter(f))
> Vector((4,16), (5,25))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
val f = (xy: (Int, Int)) => xy._1 > 3
println (L.filter (f))
```

If you do

```
val f = (x: Int, y: Int) => x > 3
```

you define a function which takes two ints, which is not the same as a function which takes a pair of ints as parameter.

Compare:

```
scala> val f = (x: Int, y: Int) => x > 3
f: (Int, Int) => Boolean = <function2>

scala> val f = (xy: (Int, Int)) => xy._1 > 3
f: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean = <function1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite your function to explicitely useing Tuple2 (as suggested by missingfaktor and user unknown), you can define a implicit method to do it automatically. This lets the function f untouched (you aren't forced to always call it with a Tuple2 parameter) and easier to understand, because you still use the identifiers x and y.

```
implicit def fun2ToTuple[A,B,Res](f:(A,B)=>Res):((A,B))=>Res = 
  (t:(A,B)) => f(t._1, t._2)
val L = for (x <- (1 to 5)) yield (x, x * x)
val f = (x: Int, y: Int) => x > 3
val g = (x: Int, y: Int) => x % 2 > y % 3
L.filter(f)    //> Vector((4,16), (5,25))
L.filter(g)    //> Vector((3,9))
f(0,1)         //> false
f((4,2))       //> true
```

Now every Function2 can also be used as a Function1 with an Tuple2 as parameter, because it uses the implicit method to convert the function if needed.

For functions with more than two parameters the implicit defs looks similiar:

```
implicit def fun3ToTuple[A,B,C,Res](f:(A,B,C)=>Res):((A,B,C))=>Res = 
  (t:(A,B,C)) => f(t._1, t._2, t._3)
implicit def fun4ToTuple[A,B,C,D,Res](f:(A,B,C,D)=>Res):((A,B,C,D))=>Res = 
  (t:(A,B,C,D)) => f(t._1, t._2, t._3, t._4)
...
```