# Clarifying strange case of Function vs Method syntax in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a function:

```
val encodeKeyValueArraysObject = (types: List[String], values: List[Json]) => { ... }
```

Which the compiler deduced the type as

```
(List[String], List[Json]) => Json
```

When I try to compose it with another function the Scala compiler complain. That  is, in

`encodeKeyValueArraysObject.compose`

compose goes red in Intellij and the compiler is not happy either. It says that compose is not a member.

However, when I write

```
encodeKeyValueArraysObject.tupled
```

which gets the type

```
((List[String], List[Json])) => Json
```

The compiler  and Intellij are happy and I can compose it, as in

```
encodeKeyValueArraysObject.tupled compose g
```

I understand the later type, and it makes sense, my function is taking a tuple.

What I don't get is what is it  that I wrote in the first place, it is not a def, function are either curried or take tuples, hence what exactly is this, if it is not a method either:

```
val encodeKeyValueArraysObject = (types: List[String], values: List[Json]) => { ... }
(List[String], List[Json]) => Json
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137522

Comment: `Function2[A, B, C]` and `Function1[Tuple2[A, B], C]` are different types.

Comment: I see thank you. So when I  said, function are either curried or take tuples, that was an Haskell assumption, not a Scala one.

Comment: The curried one would be `Function1[A, Function1[B, C]]`. It's different from the both above :)

Comment: Out of curiosity and maybe that is a stretch, but  what's the point of those FunctionN where N > 1

Comment: Yes you are right, but in both, wether curried or tupled, you can compose it. Looks like haskell to me. You can have tuple too. Hence I wonder  what's the use  of function that can't compose ? They must be useful for other stuff, that i don't see, maybe you do no ?

Comment: I guess functions just reflect methods. Method types `def foo(a: A, b: B): C`, `def foo(ab: (A, B)): C`, `def foo(a: A)(b: B): C`, `def foo(a: A): B => C`, `def foo: A => B => C`, `def foo(): A => B => C`, `def foo: (A, B) => C`, `def foo: ((A, B)) => C` are all different. So there could be different function types. The more flexibility the better? :)

Comment: Got it, yes maybe better or confusing lol . Either way thank you so much for taking the time !

Comment: If there are two ways of doing something Scala normally chooses to have both :)

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/897 https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4311